# can't ping with one iface after bonding

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface

Since i've bonded (active-backup) eth0 & wlan0 on debian stretch i'm no able to ping a specific device on my LAN with ETH0 anymore.

Every device in my LAN is able to ping in both ways
Problem persist even after changing IP address of the device
All protocols affected (not only ICMP)
Works perfectly with WLAN0
Allows all incoming/outgoing connections with IPTables
Targeted device IP is 192.168.1.XX

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
    bond-master     bond0
    bond-mode       active-backup

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
    bond-master     bond0
    bond-mode       active-backup

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.39
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.1.254
    dns-nameservers 9.9.9.9 192.168.1.254
    bond-mode active-backup
    bond-miimon 200
    bond-downdelay 200
    bond-updelay 200
    bond-slaves none
    bond-primary eth0
    bond-fail_over_mac none
    hw-address b8:27:eb:ff:12:34
```

**route**

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 bond0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 bond0
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing bonding mode to load-balancing "fixed" the issue.